# how to ensure rails multiselect input field passes all values correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

so, I've got a form inside a bootstrap modal.

when the modal loads, some javascript calls to the server to figure out what the current user has already chosen (this is an edit modal).  once the server response returns, the form select sets itself to the values that the user has already chosen as is demonstrated in the below screenshot.

[image: https://cl.ly/image/0u352k2F3Z2C/Image%202015-04-01%20at%205.02.36%20PM.png]

My problem occurs when the form is submitted.  The params being sent to the server have the key 'room_object_id' that points to a single value.  Naming issues of that key aside, I need that key to point to an array of values or a string or any structure that will hold multiple values and this is not the case, as demonstrated by the below screenshot.

[image: https://cl.ly/image/1o0z1U160N0S/Image%202015-04-01%20at%205.04.56%20PM.png]

My form is being generated by

```
<%= form_for :student, url: student_path, html: {class: 'form-horizontal sync'}, method: :put do |f| %>

<%= f.select(:room_object_id, options_for_select(@rooms.map {|room| [ room['name'], room['objectId'] ]}),{multiple: 'true', include_blank: ''} , {:class => 'select2-init form-control force-full-width', required: 'true', multiple: 'true', name: 'room_object_id'}) %>

<% end %>
```

I'm a bit unclear how select2 and the html form are working together and I have a feeling my problems are related to this.  I'm also a bit unclear of the different usages of rails `select`, `collection_select` and `options_for_select`.  I've looked at other SO posts on this topic but nothing pointed me in the right direction.  Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you just check to confirm that a `<select>` is being generated in the HTML? It sounds like either you are trying to retrieve the array of selections incorrectly, or there is an issue generating the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the JavaScript required to run select2?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#id_of_your_select_field").select2();
});
```

If you are, is your JavaScript console displaying any errors?

Comment: there were def no js errors, I ended up cannabalizing some other code and moved from `f.select` to `f.collection_select` and it cleaned up the behavior.  There was some subtle difference in the html being rendered that I couldn't quite notice (i think due to the the select2 html injection).